# resize image on mouseover keeps blinking

Tags: javascript, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I have this code and whenever I put the mouse over the first picture in the table it works fine but when I put the mouse over the second picture the picture enlarges but starts blinking. At the moment I only have two pictures from the database so I don't know if the same thing will happen to the other pictures as soon as the database is populated.
Other than that everything else seems to be working fine.

```
<table id="datatable-fixed-header" class="table table-striped table-colored table-teal">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>
        ID
      </th>
      <th>
        Picture
      </th>
      <th>
        ЕМБГ
      </th>
      <th>
        Name
      </th>
      <th>
        Occupation
      </th>
      <th>
        Active
      </th>
      <th>
        Commands
      </th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    @foreach (var item in Model.OrderByDescending(x => x.sysDateUpdated)) {
    <tr>
      <td>
        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.ID)
      </td>
      <td>

        @{ var imageDataURL = ""; if (item.Image != null) { string imageBase64Data = Convert.ToBase64String(item.Image); imageDataURL = string.Format("data:image/jpeg;base64,{0}", imageBase64Data); }
        <img src="@imageDataURL" class="thumb-md" border=0 onmouseover="show(this)" onmouseout="hide(this)" />
        <div id="enlarge_images" style="position: absolute; "></div>
        }


      </td>
      <td>
        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.EMB)
      </td>
      <td>
        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.FullName)
      </td>
      <td>
        @{ var empInfo = item.PersonEmployments.FirstOrDefault(x => !x.DateFinish.HasValue); } @(empInfo != null ? empInfo.Occupation.Title : "n\\a")
      </td>
      <td>
        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Active)
      </td>
      <td>
        @if (!Tamacs.Client.Web.Properties.Settings.Default.PantheonIntegrated) {
        <button title="Промени податоци" onclick="location.href='@Url.Action(" Edit ", "Person ", new{id=item.ID})'" class="btn btn-icon btn-xs waves-effect waves-light btn-orange"> <i class="fa fa-edit"></i> </button> }
        <button title="Информации за работен однос" onclick="location.href='@Url.Action(" Index ", "Employment ", new{id=item.ID})'" clas class="btn btn-icon btn-xs waves-effect waves-light btn-default"> <i class="fa fa-suitcase"></i> </button> @if (item.Active)
        {
        <button title="Преглед листа на картички" onclick="location.href='@Url.Action(" PersonCardsList ", "Person ", new{personId=item.ID})'" class="btn btn-icon btn-xs waves-effect waves-light btn-default"> <i class="fa fa-list"></i> </button> }
      </td>
    </tr>
    }
  </tbody>
</table>

<script>
  function show(_this) {
    document.getElementById("enlarge_images").innerHTML = "<img src='" + _this.src + "'+'width=350 height=120' >";
  }

  function hide(_this) {
    document.getElementById("enlarge_images").innerHTML = "";
  }
</script>
```

Comment: That's all very interesting, but what's the question ?

Answer (score 0):

The problem that you faced is because when the enlarge_images div is showed, div will cover your main image that causes to call image's mouse out event and also because you create multiple divs with the same id(in HTML you must create unique id). and be aware when you use position absolute the location of div is related to the nearest parent element that has a position with relative value.
I recommend that you should remove mouse out event from your main image and add it to enlarge image tag (not div)

change functions

```
function show(_this,_div)
{
    _div.innerHTML 
    = "<img src='" + _this.src + "'+'width=350 height=120'"
    + " onmouseout=\"hide(this," _div.id + ")\" />";
}
function hide(_this,_div)
{
    _div.innerHTML = "";
}
```

change HTML

```
var enlargeId = "enlarge_images" + i;

<img src="https://sep.ir//Data/Sites/1/media/icons/toolbar/724.png" style="width:25px;" class= "thumb-md" border = 0 onmouseover="show(this,document.getElementById('@enlargeId')" />
<div id="@enlargeId" style="position: absolute; "></div>
```